# errors while moving from phantomJS to headless chrome for rspec feature specs while clicking on an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use https://thoughtbot.com/blog/headless-feature-specs-with-chrome instead of poltergeist which I have been using until now.

My earlier setup for poltergeist and phantomJS was :

```
Gemfile:
gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
gem 'poltergeist'
```

and in the spec_helper.rb

```
spec_helper.rb :
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:phantomjs => Phantomjs.path, :timeout => 250})
end
```

Now that I want to move to headless_chrome I've done the following:

Changes in Gemfile

```
Gemfile:
gem 'capybara-selenium'
gem 'webdrivers'
```

I have removed the poltergeist and phantomJS related gems.

Changes in spec_helper.rb

```
spec_helper.rb :
require 'webdrivers'
require "selenium/webdriver"

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  chromeOptions: { args: %w(headless disable-gpu) }
)

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
  browser: :chrome,
  desired_capabilities: capabilities
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

But somehow clicking on an element doesn't work:

```
find("#element_id").click
expect(page).to have_css("#element_on_page_after_clicking")
```

It gives me this error saying the selector isn't present.

Which means that clicking on element isn't working.

It would be very helpful if someone can let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure how to know the version. But removing js: true from the scenario solved the problem.

Comment: @aria Removing js: true doesn't solve the problem, it just means you're running the test in a fake browser that doesn't support JS (rack_test driver)- My guess is it was failing before because you have a JS error in your page -- check your developer console and fix any JS errors you have.